# How to array unique in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data like this:

| Cage Type |
| --- |
| Open House, Open House |
|  |
|  |

How to make it like this? so I can get a unique list.

| Cage Type | Unique Cage |
| --- | --- |
| Open House, Open House | Open House |
|  |  |
|  |  |

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2, ", ",0))))
```

[image]

### Arrayformula

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(r, IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(r, ", ",0)))),"")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(ROW(A:A)&"​"&SPLIT(A:A, ", ", )&",", A:A<>""))), "​"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2<>',' group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", ),,9^9)), ",$", )))
```

[image]